# How can I get the upload progress?

Tags: ios, progress, drive

I use Google official documentation for the Drive to upload files, but don't know how to upload progress to obtain.The official document said

[Listening to the download progress](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#listening_to_the_download_progress)

[image]

Comment: Please embed the image withing the question itself, instead of linking to an external url.

Comment: @Konamiman the OP doesn't have the enough reputation to embed the image in a post

Comment: Ops, I didn't notice that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this to upload a file to drive and listen progress:

```
GTLServiceDrive *driveService = ...;
NSString *title = @"hello.txt";
NSString *content = @"Hello world";
NSString *mimeType = @"text/plain";

GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
metadata.title = title;

NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:mimeType];
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:metadata
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
GTLServiceTicket *uploadTicket = [driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];


[uploadTicket setUploadProgressBlock:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, unsigned long long totalBytesWritten, unsigned long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {
     // progress here
 }];
```